# How to include two \includegraphics in a single \newcommand figure?

Tags: errors, includegraphics, compilation-error

I have a short command to include images with a caption in my document as follows:

```
\newcommand{\image}[4][1.0]{\begin{figure}[tp]%\image[scale]{path}{label}{caption}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{Figures/#2}
\decoRule
\caption{#4}
\label{fig:#3}
\end{figure}}
```

This works fine. However, if I try to add a second newcommand to place two images next to each other, the file fails to compile. The command I'm trying to add is:

```
\newcommand{\images2}[4]{\begin{figure}[tp]%\image[scale]{path1}{path2}{label}{caption}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Figures/#1}
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{Figures/#2}
\decoRule
\caption{#4}
\label{fig:#3}
\end{figure}}
```

The log gives

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
! Undefined control sequence.
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@tempb.
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \filename@base.
! Illegal parameter number in definition of  .
! LaTeX Error: File `Figures/##1' not found.
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@tempb.
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \filename@base.
! Illegal parameter number in definition of  .
! LaTeX Error: File `Figures/##2' not found.
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
! Undefined control sequence.
! Undefined control sequence.
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \caption@tempa.
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \caption@tempa.
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \caption@tempa.
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal mode.
! Undefined control sequence.
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \caption@tempa.
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \caption@tempa.
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \caption@tempa.
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a.
```

The build fails immediately when adding the new command, even when not using it. The build does not fail when placing the contents of the new command in text manually.

---

Finally, I believe I cannot use equations to define the width of the image. Is there a way to make the sizing of the two images dynamic, somewhat like

```
\newcommand{\images2}[5][0.5]{\begin{figure}[tp]%\image[scale]{path1}{path2}{label}{caption}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{Figures/#2}
\includegraphics[width=(1-#1)\textwidth]{Figures/#3}
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not use digits in command names call it `\imagetwo` or `\imageb` or anything that is not `\image2`

Also you must not have a word space between the images, or you need to make them smaller to allow the space

```
\newcommand{\twoimages}[5][0.5]{\begin{figure}[tp]%\image[scale]{path1}{path2}{label}{caption}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{Figures/#2}%
\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr \textwidth-#1\textwidth\relax]{Figures/#3}
...
```

Comment: Thanks. Just removing the number didn't work, which is why I thought that wasn't it. But using your entire example, it works great now.